# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in node_redis hgetall function

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, redis, asynccallback, node-redis

I have the following code generating the error:

```
leagueclient.hgetall userLeagueKey, getLeagueInfo
```

I've verified that the key is correct, and getLeagueInfo executes correctly with the correct return value, but in between I get the Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Debug says it's in hgetall.

I turned on debug messages in node_redis

```
send 127.0.0.1:6379 id 2: *2
$7
hgetall
$14
userLeagueId:0

send_command buffered_writes: 0  should_buffer: false
true
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
net read 127.0.0.1:6379 id 2: *6
$11
challengeId
$1
0
$10
leagueName
$5
Oatmo
$22
currentDiscussionEntry
$1
2
```

So the error happens after sending the request and getting the result.

Any idea what could be creating the error, and alternatively the best way to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here turned out to be trying to return results from the function instead of passing the results via a callback. I'm sure this is a common problem for new programmers using node, so I thought I would mention it. All functions which depend on external accesses must work with a callback.